# How to use itertools combinations in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, combinations

I have a data frame with 4 columns like this

```
Asset1 Asset2 Asset3 Asset4 

 a      b      c      d  
 e      f      g      h
```

I want to create a column using `itertools.combinations` to give me a result of unique combinations, so ideally the output will be:

```
  Asset1 Asset2 Asset3 Asset4   test

  a      b      c      d        [abc, abd, bcd, acd]

  e      f      g      h        [efg, efh, egh, fgh]
```

I tried using `.join()` and combinations but does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

I suggest using `lambda` row-wise (`axis=1`):

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Asset1':('a','e'), 'Asset2': ('b','f'), 'Asset3': ('c', 'g'),  'Asset4': ('d', 'h')})
df['combinations'] = df.apply(lambda r: list(combinations(r, 3)), axis=1)

print(df)
```

The output:

```
  Asset1                      ...                                                       combinations
0      a                      ...                       [(a, b, c), (a, b, d), (a, c, d), (b, c, d)]
1      e                      ...                       [(e, f, g), (e, f, h), (e, g, h), (f, g, h)]

[2 rows x 5 columns]
```

You can also skip `list(combinations...` if you are later only iterating over the combinations - in this way you will save some memory and delay the computation to the moment of access to `df['combinations']`:

```
df['combinations'] = df.apply(lambda r: combinations(r, 3), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Then you will get a pretty cryptic objects in the `combinations` column:

```
  Asset1                        ...                                                               combinations
0      a                        ...                          <itertools.combinations object at 0x0000022392...
1      e                        ...                          <itertools.combinations object at 0x0000022392...

[2 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. While I was running this code, it shows an error message: 'list' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0'. Do you have any idea on this?